# write to file \t creates spaces not tabs

Tags: python

So, I have a list of lists and trying to write the values to a file with **tab** delimited;

```
sorted_results=[
   ["test1", 01],
   ["test2", 02],
]

with open('outfile.txt', 'a') as write_file:
    for i in sorted_results:
        write_file.write("{}\t{}\n".format(i[0], i[1]))
```

The end result comes out as:

```
test1 01
test2 02
```

Values are space delimited not tab. What am I missing? If I add a space before `\t` then end result will have a **space** and a **tab** between the values.

Comment: Are you sure it's a space, and not just a short tab due to tab stops?

Comment: Tip: 4 spaces or the `{}` button on the editor will indent a block of code. Back-ticks are for `in-line` code

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm not sure if it's a short tab. How can I actually write a tab or is it something to do with the text editor?

Comment: What happens if you print _2_ tabs? Does it appear as 2 spaces or more? If the latter (which it will be) then it is due to your editor's tab stops..

Comment: @mhawke it prints a space and an actual tab.

Comment: Your code is broken, and what's more your claimed result doesn't match mine even after fixing the obvious errors (e.g. there are no `0`s in my `output.txt`). Are you sure this is the actual code you are testing? How are you checking whether the file contains a space or a tab? What does `xxd outfile.txt` say?

Comment: do a simple test `write_file.write("{}\t\t\t{}\n".format(i[0], i[1]))`

Comment: Works fine on my box. You must be reading the file in a text editor that converts tabs to spaces

Comment: @DanielWagner, I've fixed the code. I'm checking the file via IDE and notepad++ visually. so therefore like I said I'm not sure if it's a short tab or an actual space. I've posted what the file says towards the end of my question

Comment: I had the same issue of missing tab: when I was displaying the output with 'cat' and copying it to Excel! When I opened the file properly with text-editor the tab was there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the file back in and inspect the resulting data.

```
>>> open('outfile.txt').read()
'test1\t1\ntest2\t2\n'
```

This shows that the tab character is indeed written to the file. If you are still in doubt use a hex editor to view the characters.

Comment: It was my IDE and the text editor. I've read back the file and got `test01\t01....` Thank you